# Pandas: Working with missing values in monthly data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I want to work with a df with monthly data.
Important: The data aggregates over the months.
Looking like this:

```
Month   | Sum
01-2021    1
02-2021    4
03-2021    9
04-2021    11
05-2021    15
06-2021    16
08-2021    21
09-2021    25
```

Now I have two task:

1. **Detect if a month is missing and insert the month.**
   In this example July 2021 (07-2021) is missing. In this case I want to create a new row with the month and use the previous sum (as this month does not contribute anything). But The df has to be complete without missing months.
2. **Quickly change between monthly and quarterly display.**
   Transforming in:

```
Month   | Sum
Q1-2021    9
Q2-2021    16
Q3-2021    25
```

**What I have already done:**
Converted the month column into datetime type as I think this might be the first step to the best solution here.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Pointer 1: You can do is to create a `DataFrame` for 12 months. Then left merge your monthly data to the DataFrame.

Pointer 2: You can use `pd.Grouper`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would work with the `resample` function. If `Month` is a column of the dataframe you should convert it into an index (`df.set_index('Month')`) and then resample, either on a monthly or quarterly basis:

```
ts.resample('M').bfill()
```

or

```
ts.resample('Q').bfill()
```

or one after the other. `bfill` fills the missing values based on the previous available record(s).

Comment: Just to add one thing, if you want to fill with NaNs, you can use `df = df.resample('Q').asfreq()`